# display data from 2 assets using single query in hyperledger faric ?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i have these two assets : 
1] 
asset bloodBankInformations identified by bloodBankId {
  o String bloodBankId
  o contact bloodBankContactDetails
  --> bloodData bloodBankBloodData
}

2] 
asset bloodData extends bloodBankInformations {
  o String bloodDatakey
  o bloodquotas bloodquota
}

now i want to query on this asset such that i can get data from both assets in one single query.

Answer (score 0):

Composer Queries are run against a single Asset or Participant registry.  There is no 'join' as you might see in a relational database.

However for your example it is possible to use a **Filter** on the REST server to filter the results (like a Query) and *resolve* the relationship of relationship fields.

Before showing you my example I wonder if you really wanted to 'extend' original asset?  So I have simplified your model in my example - but the same principle works if you did intend to extend.

**Model**:

```
asset bloodBankInformations identified by bloodBankId { 
  o String bloodBankId 
  o contact bloodBankContactDetails 
  --> bloodData bloodBankBloodData 
}

asset bloodData extends bloodBankInformations {
  o String bloodDatakey
  o bloodquotas bloodquota 
}
```

**Filter**:

On the REST server used on **GET** on the endpoint **/blookBankInformations**

`{"where":{"bloodBankId":"BB03"},"include":"resolve"}`

My **Response Body**:

```
[
{
"$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.bloodBankInformations",
"bloodBankId": "BB03",
"bloodBankContactDetails": "Diferent address!",
"bloodBankBloodData": {
  "$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.bloodData",
  "bloodDatakey": "BL04",
  "bloodquota": "Quota BBBB"
 }
}
]
```

There is some additional information in the [Composer Knowledge Wiki](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#filters) on filters.